# Recursively render tree in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree

I have a model that acts_as_tree and I want to render it to a nested HTML-list:

```
<ol>
 <li> Content goes here
  <ol> recursion
    <li>goes</li>
  <ol> here
 </li>
</ol>
```

This should normally be easy with a recursive function. But rails forces the strict separation between code and content.

What is the 'rails way' to recursively render the tree as HTML-List and preserve that separation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

- The partial way
- The recursive function way

I don't know how `acts_as_tree` works, but I'll demonstrate how `acts_as_nested_set` works, which should be similar.

Since you ask about the recursive way, you can separate content from ruby in a function on the view scope:

```
<%
  def draw_tree(node)
    node.children.each do |child|
%>
      <li><%= child.name %>
<%
          if child.children.any?
%>
              <ol><% draw_tree(child) %></ol>
<%
          end
%>
      </li>
<%
    end; nil
  end
%>
```

Then, to render the tree for all your root nodes (I repeat, this is for `acts_as_nested_set`, you will have to adapt it - that shouldn't be hard to do):

```
<ol>
    <% Model.roots.each do |node| %>
        <li>
            <%= node.name %>
            <% if node.children.any? %>
                <ol><%= draw_tree(node) %></ol>
            <% end %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

All the above code should be in the same template (`.html.erb`). Of course, you can *partialize* it.

The way to do it with partials is similar to the above, but instead of calling a function you render a partial for the node. But I have the impression (which I have not tested thought) that the recursive function should be slightly faster to render than the partial.

**update**

For `acts_as_tree` you just need:

`root=Model.where(parent_id:nil).first`

So:

```
<% root=Model.where(parent_id:nil).first %>
<ol>
    <% root.children.each do |node| %>
        <li>
            <%= node.name %>
            <% if node.children.any? %>
                <ol><%= draw_tree(node) %></ol>
            <% end %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Great answer.

The missing information that
>  you can separate content from ruby in a function on the view scope
was an important stone to cause my stumble. As it is obviously possible to do recursive logic in the view file it seems my problem was a pseudo-problem.

Thanks.

Comment: @von spotz, the truth is I was looking for that a while ago, resolved into tying something of my own... it worked, so here it is :)

Comment: That nil at the end of the function is surprisingly important for us newbies.  I was getting all kinds of escaped end tags showing up in the output.